# dict in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Я спарсил некоторые данные, теперь мне необходимо преобразовать данные из dict в dataframe.
С pandas не дружу, поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь

```
df = pd.DataFrame(text)
print(df)
```

Как - то не наглядно

```
0   {'film_name': '21 мост', 'film_genres': ['боев...
1   {'film_name': 'FORD против FERRARI', 'film_gen...
2   {'film_name': 'Аббатство Даунтон', 'film_genre...
3   {'film_name': 'Арахисовый сокол', 'film_genres...
4   {'film_name': 'Война токов', 'film_genres': ['...
5   {'film_name': 'Давай разведемся', 'film_genres...
```

`text`:

```py
{
  'filmes': [
    {
      'film_name': '21 мост', 
      'film_genres': ['боевик', 'триллер'], 
      'cinames': [
        {
          'cinema': 'Nescafe-IMAX', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:55', 
              'price': '190 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Каро 13 Кунцево', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '430 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Каро 8 Теплый Стан', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '350 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Киномакс Мозаика', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:50', 
              'price': '290 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Предоставьте в своём вопросе пример входных данных (переменной `text`)

Comment: ниже в dict указал я

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно развернуть словарь в датафрейм с помощью [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

```
In [51]: from pandas.io.json import json_normalize                                                 

In [52]: # Преобразуем списки жанров в строки                                                      

In [53]: for f in d['filmes']: 
    ...:     f['film_genres'] = ', '.join(f['film_genres']) 
    ...:                                                                                           

In [54]: d                                                                                         
Out[54]: 
{'filmes': [{'film_name': '21 мост',
   'film_genres': 'боевик, триллер',
   'cinames': [{'cinema': 'Nescafe-IMAX',
     'sessions': [{'time': '23:55', 'price': '190 ₽', 'format': '2D'}]},
    {'cinema': 'Каро 13 Кунцево',
     'sessions': [{'time': '23:25', 'price': '430 ₽', 'format': '2D'}]},
    {'cinema': 'Каро 8 Теплый Стан',
     'sessions': [{'time': '23:25', 'price': '350 ₽', 'format': '2D'}]},
    {'cinema': 'Киномакс Мозаика',
     'sessions': [{'time': '23:50', 'price': '290 ₽', 'format': '2D'}]}]}]}

In [55]: df = (json_normalize(d['filmes'],  
    ...:                      record_path=['cinames', 'sessions'], 
    ...:                      meta=['film_name', 'film_genres', ['cinames', 'cinema']]) 
    ...:       .rename(columns={'cinames.cinema': 'cinema'}) 
    ...:       .reindex(columns=['film_name', 'film_genres', 'cinema', 'format', 'time', 'price']) 
    ...: )                                                                                         

In [56]: df                                                                                        
Out[56]: 
  film_name      film_genres              cinema format   time  price
0   21 мост  боевик, триллер        Nescafe-IMAX     2D  23:55  190 ₽
1   21 мост  боевик, триллер     Каро 13 Кунцево     2D  23:25  430 ₽
2   21 мост  боевик, триллер  Каро 8 Теплый Стан     2D  23:25  350 ₽
3   21 мост  боевик, триллер    Киномакс Мозаика     2D  23:50  290 ₽
```

При множестве фильмов можно указать несколько столбцов в качестве индекса:

```
In [80]: df                                                                                        
Out[80]: 
   film_name      film_genres              cinema format   time  price
0    21 мост  боевик, триллер        Nescafe-IMAX     2D  23:55  190 ₽
1    21 мост  боевик, триллер        Nescafe-IMAX     2D  23:50  290 ₽
2    21 мост  боевик, триллер     Каро 13 Кунцево     2D  23:25  430 ₽
3    21 мост  боевик, триллер     Каро 13 Кунцево     2D  23:25  430 ₽
4    21 мост  боевик, триллер     Каро 13 Кунцево     2D  23:55  190 ₽
5    21 мост  боевик, триллер  Каро 8 Теплый Стан     2D  23:25  350 ₽
6    21 мост  боевик, триллер    Киномакс Мозаика     2D  23:50  290 ₽
7    22 мост  боевик, триллер        Nescafe-IMAX     2D  23:55  190 ₽
8    22 мост  боевик, триллер        Nescafe-IMAX     2D  23:50  290 ₽
9    22 мост  боевик, триллер     Каро 13 Кунцево     2D  23:25  430 ₽
10   22 мост  боевик, триллер     Каро 13 Кунцево     2D  23:25  430 ₽
11   22 мост  боевик, триллер     Каро 13 Кунцево     2D  23:55  190 ₽
12   22 мост  боевик, триллер  Каро 8 Теплый Стан     2D  23:25  350 ₽
13   22 мост  боевик, триллер    Киномакс Мозаика     2D  23:50  290 ₽

In [81]: df.set_index(['film_name', 'cinema', 'film_genres'])                                      
Out[81]: 
                                             format   time  price
film_name cinema             film_genres                         
21 мост   Nescafe-IMAX       боевик, триллер     2D  23:55  190 ₽
                             боевик, триллер     2D  23:50  290 ₽
          Каро 13 Кунцево    боевик, триллер     2D  23:25  430 ₽
                             боевик, триллер     2D  23:25  430 ₽
                             боевик, триллер     2D  23:55  190 ₽
          Каро 8 Теплый Стан боевик, триллер     2D  23:25  350 ₽
          Киномакс Мозаика   боевик, триллер     2D  23:50  290 ₽
22 мост   Nescafe-IMAX       боевик, триллер     2D  23:55  190 ₽
                             боевик, триллер     2D  23:50  290 ₽
          Каро 13 Кунцево    боевик, триллер     2D  23:25  430 ₽
                             боевик, триллер     2D  23:25  430 ₽
                             боевик, триллер     2D  23:55  190 ₽
          Каро 8 Теплый Стан боевик, триллер     2D  23:25  350 ₽
          Киномакс Мозаика   боевик, триллер     2D  23:50  290 ₽
```

Comment: Очень простой способ, но попробуйте его на примере данных, которые я предоставил в своём ответе, когда есть несколько фильмов, а в кинотеатрах несколько сеансов. Мне кажется, не очень удобный формат вывода данных. Возможно, это тоже можно исправить, используя этот метод.

Comment: С этим датафреймом можно делать, что угодно. Я дополнил ответ. Использовал ваш пример данных, только изменил название второго фильма.

Answer (score 1):

Немного дополнил входные данные для большей наглядности:

```py
text = {
  'filmes': [
    {
      'film_name': '21 мост', 
      'film_genres': ['боевик', 'триллер'], 
      'cinames': [
        {
          'cinema': 'Nescafe-IMAX', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:55', 
              'price': '190 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            },
            {
              'time': '23:50', 
              'price': '290 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Каро 13 Кунцево', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '430 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            },
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '430 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            },
            {
              'time': '23:55', 
              'price': '190 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Каро 8 Теплый Стан', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '350 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Киномакс Мозаика', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:50', 
              'price': '290 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      'film_name': '21 мост', 
      'film_genres': ['боевик', 'триллер'], 
      'cinames': [
        {
          'cinema': 'Nescafe-IMAX', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:55', 
              'price': '190 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            },
            {
              'time': '23:50', 
              'price': '290 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Каро 13 Кунцево', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '430 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            },
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '430 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            },
            {
              'time': '23:55', 
              'price': '190 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Каро 8 Теплый Стан', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:25', 
              'price': '350 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          'cinema': 'Киномакс Мозаика', 
          'sessions': [
            {
              'time': '23:50', 
              'price': '290 ₽', 
              'format': '2D'
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Фильма теперь два (я ленивый, поэтому у них одинаковые данные) + в некоторых кинотеатрах теперь по несколько сеансов.

Моё решение задачи:

```py
import pandas as pd
text = {} # тут входные данные, которые приводил выше

# добавляем первую строку-заголовок
dat = [['Фильм', 'Жанры', 'Кинотеарты', 'Время', 'Цена', ' Формат']]
# работаем с каждым фильмом отдельно
for film in text['filmes']:
    # для удобства выносим в отдельные переменные жанры и кинотеатры
    film_genres = film['film_genres']
    cinames = film['cinames']

    # узнаём, сколько же всего строк будут занимать все данные о нашем фильме
    n = len(film_genres) if len(film_genres) > len(cinames) else len(cinames)
    k = 0
    for c in cinames:
        k += len(c['sessions'])
    n = k if k > n else n

    # т.к. для предыдущей операции k себя исчерпал, и он не нужен, используем его в других целях
    # k - количество сеансов, которые осталось вывести для текущего кинотеатра
    k = 0
    # cin - номер текущего кинотеатра
    cin = 0
    # работаем с каждой строкой текущего фильма
    for i in range(n):
        # создаём список, который содержит поля строки
        l = []

        # если это первая строка, в ней нужно вывести заголовок. Иначе - выводим пустую строку, чтобы просто занять ячейку
        if i == 0:
            l.append(film['film_name'])
        else:
            l.append('')

        # если i меньше, чем количество жанров - на этой строке можно вывести жанр. Иначе - занимаем ячейку пустой строкой
        if i < len(film_genres):
            l.append(film_genres[i])
        else:
            l.append('')
        
        # если все строки для предыдущего кинотеатра уже выведены (осталось вывести 0 строк), то
        if not k:
            # записываем название следующего кинотеатра, в k - сколько строк выделить для этого кинотеатра (сколько сессий в этом театре), увеличиваем индекс кинотеатра
            l.append(cinames[cin]['cinema'])
            k = len(cinames[cin]['sessions'])
            cin += 1
        else:
            # если выведены ещё не все строки - просто занимаем ячейку, где должно быть название (чтобы не дублировать его по 100 раз)
            l.append('')
        
        # добавляем время, цену и формат текущего сеанса. 
        # Сеансы начинаются с конца (тот, что указан последним, выведется первым. 
        # Если нужен прямой порядок - меняем [k-1] на [1-k]
        l.append(cinames[cin-1]['sessions'][k-1]['time'])
        l.append(cinames[cin-1]['sessions'][k-1]['price'])
        l.append(cinames[cin-1]['sessions'][k-1]['format'])
        # переходим к следующему сеансу
        k -= 1
        # сохраняем полученную строку в наш список
        dat.append(l)
  
# список всех строк укомплектован, делаем из него датафрейм и выводим в консоль
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
print(df)
```

Результат:

```
          0        1                   2      3      4        5
0     Фильм    Жанры          Кинотеарты  Время   Цена   Формат
1   21 мост   боевик        Nescafe-IMAX  23:50  290 ₽       2D
2            триллер                      23:55  190 ₽       2D
3                        Каро 13 Кунцево  23:55  190 ₽       2D
4                                         23:25  430 ₽       2D
5                                         23:25  430 ₽       2D
6                     Каро 8 Теплый Стан  23:25  350 ₽       2D
7                       Киномакс Мозаика  23:50  290 ₽       2D
8   21 мост   боевик        Nescafe-IMAX  23:50  290 ₽       2D
9            триллер                      23:55  190 ₽       2D
10                       Каро 13 Кунцево  23:55  190 ₽       2D
11                                        23:25  430 ₽       2D
12                                        23:25  430 ₽       2D
13                    Каро 8 Теплый Стан  23:25  350 ₽       2D
14                      Киномакс Мозаика  23:50  290 ₽       2D
```

Возможно, у `Pandas` есть какие-то свои идеи по распаковке подобных итерируемых объектов на любых количествах уровней вложенности, но они мне неизвестны. Ценим, что имеем.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @danilshik если будет нужно, могу добавить комментарии к коду (если это достаточно важно)

Comment: добавьте, если не трудно

Comment: @danilshik обновил